# Complex Data Binding in GridView control

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have couple of tables that are related together using primary keys. When I want to display a table using a GridView and data-binding. GridView shows the primary keys of the related tables which are not useful for me! I want another column of the related table to be shown (but I still want to be able to use the id of the row of the related table for editing purposes).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="FaiulerDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FaiulerDiscription" HeaderText="FaiulerDiscription" SortExpression="FaiulerDiscription" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShiftMaster" HeaderText="ShiftMaster" SortExpression="ShiftMaster" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Approval" HeaderText="Approval" SortExpression="Approval" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RepairManId" HeaderText="RepairManId" SortExpression="RepairManId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OperatorId" HeaderText="OperatorId" SortExpression="OperatorId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Part_Id" HeaderText="Part_Id" SortExpression="Part_Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Shift_Id" HeaderText="Shift_Id" SortExpression="Shift_Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FaultType_Id" HeaderText="FaultType_Id" SortExpression="FaultType_Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Machine_Id" HeaderText="Machine_Id" SortExpression="Machine_Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RepairType_Id" HeaderText="RepairType_Id" SortExpression="RepairType_Id" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

As you see the `Faiuler` table contains many columns. I have other tables called `RepairMan`, `Machines`, `Shift` etc. so this code displays the `repairman_id` but I want the `RepairMan_Name` to be shown to the user but I still need the `RepairMan_id` for editing and deleting stuff.

**UPDATE:**

Here's the code for the DataSource could tell how to change it ? I don't know that much about I created the DataSource with Wizard not writing code .

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FaiulerDataSource" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WoodFactoryConnectionString %>" 
      SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Date], [FaiulerDiscription], [ShiftMaster], [Approval], [RepairManId], [OperatorId], [Part_Id], [Shift_Id], [FaultType_Id], [Machine_Id], [RepairType_Id] FROM [Failures] WHERE ([RepairManId] IS NULL)">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You can bind `id' to a label and hide it, so when you want to delete or edit you can find that label.

Comment: that's ok but that doesn't solve the main problem ! i want to show the 'Name'  property of the repairMan instead of he's Id which is not in the faiuler tables it's in the RepairMan table

Comment: Ok, so is there a relation between them, if yes you should change `select` query and join that table then bind it to `Name`.

Comment: i don't know how to do it ! take a look at the update ! this is my first ASP.Net project ! and i have never worked with DB before !

Comment: If `RepairMan` is seprate table you should Change the `FaiulerDataSource` select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select that field in select command like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FaiulerDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WoodFactoryConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Date], [FaiulerDiscription], [ShiftMaster], [Approval], [RepairManId], [OperatorId], [Part_Id], [Shift_Id], [FaultType_Id], [Machine_Id], [RepairType_Id],RepairMan.RepairMan_Name FROM [Failures],[RepairMan] WHERE (Failures.RepairManId IS NULL)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If there was a relation between them, I suppose there are `one-to-many` relation between `RepairMan` and `Failures` tables which means one `RepairMan` can have many `Failures` so you should join these two and change the select command like:

```
SELECT Failures.Id, Failures.Date, Failures.FaiulerDiscription, Failures.ShiftMaster, Failures.Approval,
 Failures.RepairManId,Failures.OperatorId, Failures.Part_Id, Failures.Shift_Id, Failures.FaultType_Id, Failures.Machine_Id, Failures.RepairType_Id,RepairMan.RepairMan_Name,RepairMan.FauilarId
 FROM [Failures] inner join RepairMan on RepairMan.RepairMan_Id = Failures.RepairManId WHERE (Failures.RepairManId IS NULL)
```

then you can bind Name like:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
```

Comment: yeah ! that's every repairman can have many failuers and every faiuler can have only one repair man

Comment: yeah i am changing it ! the RepairM**e**n table has id and Name should i write RepairMen.RepairMen_Id or just RepairMen.id ? another question are the [] neccesery ?

Comment: Yes if that is primary key in `RepairMan` you should , if no `Id` of `RepairMan` is as foreign key in `Failures` table you should write `RepairMan.Id = Failures.RepairManId`.

Comment: Aboute [], `SqlDataSource` generate it automatically because you may use build in keywords in your tables like `Type`, I think if it surrounded by [] then it can understand it doesn't a keyword or you can use square brackets to enclose the name. If the name does not contain any spaces or special characters (such as punctuation marks), the square brackets are optional. If the name does contain spaces or special characters, you must use the brackets.

Comment: i have test all of the possible ways . i still got "Syntax error near ',' " . i think i should simply forget about it .

Comment: Your reputation not yet enough to have a chat, so do you have TeamViewer 10, let me connect you to correct that.

Comment: i should i might have in my Hard ! if not i'll download it in a sec !

Comment: ok i have downloaded it ! where should i give you the id/pw ?

Comment: there is no request give me your id

Comment: are you from iran ? do you have Viber ? 09382712810 ! i have diffuclites in sign in to skype

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the name using the following assuming that you already included the name inside the datasource

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="RepairMan_Name" HeaderText="repair name"  />
```

and your sqldatasource should be like the following

```
SELECT [Id], [Date], [FaiulerDiscription], [ShiftMaster], [Approval], [RepairManId], [OperatorId], [Part_Id], [Shift_Id], [FaultType_Id], [Machine_Id], [RepairType_Id], [RepairMan.RepairMan_Name] AS RepairMan_Name FROM [Failures] inner join RepairMan on RepairMan.repairmanid = failures.repairmanid WHERE ([RepairManId] IS NULL)
```

Comment: they are not in the DataSource since they RepairMan is a seprate Table.

Comment: So simply update the select command of the sqldatasource to include the column name in the select list

Comment: i don't know how to do it ! coud tell me how ? i have added the datasource code in updates !

Comment: i got an incorrect syntax error near ',' it seams that something is wrong with '[RepairType_Id],RepairMan.RepairMan_Name FROM' this part.

Comment: Would check the answer now and please confirm that the select command working without issues inside the sql management studio

Comment: i don't have sql management studio ! i am using the default VS localDB for this project !

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure what is the root of this error !

Comment: still get the same error are you sure that you shouldn't use == operater instead of = ? why don't you use [] ? as i see all of the table and row names are surronded by [] ! although i have tested with and without brackets !